# Using #includes in rails, making two runs to Stocks table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In my stock portfolio app I'm looping through transaction objects to grab stock information within my portfolio show page.

```
<% @portfolio.transactions.each do |trans| %>
  <tr>
    <td class="col-md-1"><%= trans.stock.symbol %></td>
    <td class="col-md-1"><%= number_to_currency(trans.stock.last_price) %></td>
    <td class="col-md-1"><%= trans.stock.name %></td>
    <td class="col-md-1"><%= trans.stock.stock_exchange %></td>
    <td class="col-md-1"><%= trans.num_of_shares %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

My @portfolio object in portfolios_controller is defined as

```
def show
  @portfolio = Portfolio.includes(:transactions, :stocks).find(params[:id])
  @transaction = Transaction.new
end
```

My models are defined as

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :portfolio
  belongs_to :stock
end

class Stock < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactions
end

class Portfolio < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :transactions
  has_many :stocks, through: :transactions
end
```

My logs look like this when I hit a portfolio show page:

```
Started GET "/portfolios/2" for ::1 at 2016-09-24 17:59:13 -0400
Processing by PortfoliosController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  Portfolio Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "portfolios".* FROM "portfolios"
    WHERE "portfolios"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Transaction Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "transactions".* FROM "transactions"
    WHERE "transactions"."portfolio_id" IN (2)
  Stock Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "stocks".* FROM "stocks" WHERE
    "stocks"."id" IN (3, 1, 14, 9)
  Stock Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "stocks".* FROM "stocks"
  Rendered transactions/_form.html.erb (2.8ms)
  Rendered portfolios/show.html.erb within layouts/application (5.5ms)
  Rendered application/_nav.html.erb (0.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 39ms (Views: 33.8ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
```

I'm confused as to what that second Stock Load statement is doing. Why is there another trip to the database if I already have the stock objects I need.

Comment: Do you have any filters on your controller or anything else in your view that might be triggering it? What else is in the models?

Comment: I have reproduced your app as closely as I can with the information provided here, and I do not see that second `Stock Load`, so I think something is missing from your details included here.

Comment: I figured it out. I left out that I also had a Transaction form. It was grabbing stock objects for a dropdown list and that was causing the second call.

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

could you try:

```
Portfolio.includes(transactions: [:stock])
```

I think the problem might be that it included the association on the `Portfolio`, but not on the `Transaction`, meaning if you had done: `@portfolio.stocks`, it wouldn't have made another db call, but doing `@transaction.stock.name` made it to make the call.

Let me know if that works and if it makes sense?